# Representing Values As Colours with Fill Function Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Using Matlab.

This seems like a very simple problem, however I've not been able to solve it. I am looking to use the fill function (or something similar) to represent the same values with colour from a sequence of numbers.

For example:

[image]

a = [ 1 1 1 2 2 1 3 3 3 4 5 5];

Where each group of numbers are represented by a a colour. As shown below:

I have been able to do this on a bar chart, however I wanted to see if it was possible to use the fill function (or something similar) to better represent the difference in visually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I arrived at is as follows, while it may be a little more complicated and there are simple ways it works for me.

%Generate the colours based on the highest number of X
    gen_colors = rand(max(X),3);

```
%create the map store to hold each record
mapstore = [];

%assign the colours to each id
for i=1:size(X,1)

    %Obtain the correct ID ready to assign colour
    sI = X(i);

    %Pass over the correct ID for each row ID
    mapstore = [mapstore; gen_colors(sI,:)];
end

%Pass over the selected segment row colours to be formated
map = colormap(mapstore);

%Create an image with the segments to display
image(repmat(cat(3, map(:,1)', map(:,2)', map(:,3)'), 20, 1));

% Remove ticks we dont want, and add a few relavant ones
%Pass ind to highlight where the keyframes are placed on the plot
set(gca, 'ytick', 0, 'xtick', ind);

%styling
axis equal
axis tight
axis xy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to map integers to a set of colours, you can define a function which interpolates a colormap.  Colormaps are often used in heat maps and the like, e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html

You can use them to map integers to a specific color, providing you know the largest value you're going to encounter.  You've put 1 to 5, so I will use 5 as my largest integer.

```
cm = jet; % use the Jet colormap
n = 5; % largest integer

color1 = interp1(linspace(0, 1, size(cm, 1)), cm, 1/n)
color2 = interp1(linspace(0, 1, size(cm, 1)), cm, 2/n)
color3 = interp1(linspace(0, 1, size(cm, 1)), cm, 3/n)
color4 = interp1(linspace(0, 1, size(cm, 1)), cm, 4/n)
color5 = interp1(linspace(0, 1, size(cm, 1)), cm, 5/n)
```

And the results (described in RGB format) are:

```
color1 =

         0    0.3500    1.0000


color2 =

    0.1375    1.0000    0.8625


color3 =

    0.9250    1.0000    0.0750


color4 =

    1.0000    0.2875         0


color5 =

    0.5000         0         0
```

Note that I've gone a bit overkill here, given that you could have just called jet(5) and it would have given you a similar result.  The listed approach however allows you to define your own custom colormaps and interpolate them.